# Remove app from recent apps when back key pressed android

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to remove my app from recent apps when I pressed back key but it remains in recent apps if I press Home key. I have tried setting

```
<activity
       android:name=".MyActivity"
       android:launchMode="singleInstance"
       android:excludeFromRecents="true" >
</activity>
```

But it also remove when I press HOME key.
Kindly help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: does it remove or not?

Comment: What is the difference between using the home or back key (in your opinion) when leaving the application? Both return to the home screen. So I guess you will only confuse the user with this behavior. Unless you *do have* a good reasons for it, hence my question.

Comment: App removes from recent but I want my app only from recent when I press BACK key

Comment: Pressing HOME means app still running in background and BACK means user quits and not running in background.

Comment: Do you users also know this? As it is not default Android behavior

Comment: Yes, they know about this.

Comment: Try Override backbutton in the activity it self and set the singleInstance and excludefromRecents flags and then finish() the activity

Comment: @Pragnani: can you tell how I can add flags to current activity?

Answer (score 1):

**add android:excludeFromRecents="true" in activity definition  manifest file**

same Q:
[How to remove application from recent application list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762763/how-to-remove-application-from-recent-application-list)

or

```
protected void onPause() {
  finish();
}
```

or

```
android:noHistory= "true";
```

Comment: I have already mentioned in question that I have used it. It does provide that behavior which I want.

Comment: Please clarify first that what I want and then answer.