# Android app is not shown on the OS running apps list

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

As a default behavior, when an android app is running and you click the hard device Home button, you are able to see that app on the OS running apps list. but I can't see my app on the list after clicking Home button? I've used neither **android:excludeFromRecents="true"** or **android:noHistory= "true"** on my manifest file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762763/how-to-remove-application-from-recent-application-list

Comment: you may have used **android:excludeFromRecents="true"** under activity tag in Manifest file... remove that

Comment: I've used neither android:excludeFromRecents="true" or android:noHistory= "true" on my manifest file

Comment: have you modified the behavior of your app on `onPause` or something like that? maybe you close the app when it's getting minimized or something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A special thanks to those guys who asked and answered this question [How to remove application from recent application list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762763/how-to-remove-application-from-recent-application-list).
specially the gentleman [JackyLalala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3115855/jackylalala).

I just wanna to say you, don't leave the label attribute with empty string in the activity tag of your manifest. If you do this (android:label="") you won't see your app name in the OS running app list. At least remove the entire attribute or fill it with a nice string.