# Splash screen does't show after I close the app by double clicking the back button

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

When I restart the app after I exit the app on Android by double clicking the back button, there is no splash screen and icon. I used this statement to exit the app:

```
ionic.Platform.exitApp();
```

I also tried using the following, but it doesn't solve my problem.

```
navigator.app.exitApp();
```

So, I don't know how to solve it, please help me.

Comment: I think that is actually because application is minimised not closed completely. So waking up from minimise does not show splash screen.

Comment: How to close application completely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
<activity android:name="XXXX"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true" ...
```

in your `AndroidManifest.xml`'s activity declaration.

Taken from @Mannaz's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6468975/6449750).

Regards.

Comment: Hi, Vaghani. Thanks your answer. It is a solution to my problem. But I think it's not the best solution, because It directly remove the app from application list , not like another android app.

Comment: I am ionic 2 RC4. But this solution does not work for me. The application is not in the recent list, but also does not show the splash screen

Answer (score 2):

According to [documentations](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen), the way ionic2 supports this is by adding the following options to `config.xml`:

```
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="true|false" />
```

However, as of version `4.0.1` there is a bug in the plugin. When the application is closed programatically, the next time we launch the application, without closing it from recent applications, the application crashes, and says `app stopped unexpectedly`. The following is the debug log of ADB for the same:

```
12-20 09:35:50.851 30375 30375 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-20 09:35:50.851 30375 30375 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.mydomain.myapp, PID: 30375
12-20 09:35:50.851 30375 30375 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setAnimation(android.view.animation.Animation)' on a null object reference
12-20 09:35:50.851 30375 30375 E AndroidRuntime:        at org.apache.cordova.splashscreen.SplashScreen$4.run(SplashScreen.java:227)
12-20 09:35:50.851 30375 30375 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:6050)
12-20 09:35:50.851 30375 30375 E AndroidRuntime:        at org.apache.cordova.splashscreen.SplashScreen.removeSplashScreen(SplashScreen.java:217)
12-20 09:35:50.851 30375 30375 E AndroidRuntime:        at org.apache.cordova.splashscreen.SplashScreen.access$1000(SplashScreen.java:49)
12-20 09:35:50.851 30375 30375 E AndroidRuntime:        at org.apache.cordova.splashscreen.SplashScreen$5$1.run(SplashScreen.java:330)
12-20 09:35:50.851 30375 30375 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
12-20 09:35:50.851 30375 30375 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-20 09:35:50.851 30375 30375 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
12-20 09:35:50.851 30375 30375 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
12-20 09:35:50.851 30375 30375 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-20 09:35:50.851 30375 30375 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
12-20 09:35:50.851 30375 30375 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

I haved opened an [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-12277) for the same.